# Bug layout does not show some part

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout, photo

I have designed in a linear layout with a listview it is supposed to have everything shown with the whole photo and it leaves the part of likey comment but only the photo comes out and in small photos if the part comes out but in other big photos it does not

It would be nice to implement picasso but I do not know how to do it or if it can

[image: the part where not everything is show]

I attach the layouts:
this is the layout_post part of a recycler view

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_post_username"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="10h30" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_post_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="Post text has some words that I could use for a placeholder like this" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_post_display"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/imageholder" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/like_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_like"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/chill"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_likes"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comment_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_comment_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_comments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is the rowpost
is a cardview that include the layoutpost

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#212121">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:elevation="10dp">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_post" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

the content view:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.android.octa.memetixs.Activities.main.PostActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_post">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="471dp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is a small, low resolution photo here if it shows:

[image: second photo]

And here if everything is shown as it should be

Comment: `layout does not show some part` which part?

Comment: the part of the linear layout that contain the like and comment button When uploading good quality photos disappears that part as above in the photo @rafsanahmad007

Answer (score 0):

If you use a LinearLayout without weightSum attribute then it simple stacks the child views one over the other Without adjusting its dimension to fit.

Use android:weightSum attribute in the LinearLayout and  android:layout_weight  +  android:layout_height="0dp" for the child views, then if for example weightSum == 6 and a child has layout_weight == 1 then it will get 1/6 of space.

Comment: In which part should use that attribute @Tonteria24

Comment: In the layour xml